addHeader not working when building RestRequest in Test Class
I am trying to create a Test Method which will test a REST API however I keep hitting duplicate rules when I am performing upsert. I have added the addHeader('Sforce-Duplicate-Rule-Header', 'allowSave=true') to the RestRequest in order to bypass the duplicate rules however this doesn't seem to be working. Does anyone have any ideas?
TEST CLASS
@isTest
    static void registerExistingLeadWebId(){
        RestRequest req = new RestRequest();
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();

        req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/Register-Lead/';
        req.httpMethod = 'PUT';
        req.addHeader('Sforce-Duplicate-Rule-Header', 'allowSave=true');
        RestContext.request = req;
        RestContext.request.addHeader('Sforce-Duplicate-Rule-Header', 'allowSave=true');
        RestContext.response = res;


        Test.startTest();
            RegisterLeadAPI.createLead('Upsert Lead', 'dupelead@test.com', 'Test Company', '123456789');
        Test.stopTest();


Make sure that your API version is 52.0 or later, as the Sforce-Duplicate-Rule-Header is available from API version 52.0. If the header approach doesn't work, you can use Database.DMLOptions to set the duplicate rule options directly in your Apex code.

Thanks for the reply Tushar. The version is above 52.0 and unfortunately you cannot use Database.DMLOptions with upsert. It's strange as when I send the header via postman the class performs as expected it just doesn't seem to like it when adding via test method.
